# Create a bigger GitHub Network Graph

Tags: github

The Github graph is great but sometimes I would like to be able to see more than the window shown by the current GitHub UI

Is there a way to get it bigger? For example in a full-screen mode?

Answer (score 0):

No Github's built-in feature is exist. But you can "hack" by doing like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190864/3728901