# How to get the full github.com visualization of the /network of a repo

Tags: git, github, graph, visualization

**EDIT:** This is supposed to be a gift for my mother, If I have to I'll drag and drop it and stitch a bunch of screen-prints together... however the resource has to live on the website somewhere. I do believe that at least someone on this site knows how to do this.

**EDIT:** So I dug around on this somemore and found that if you put /meta after network you get a JSON. Also /chunk was in the page source, but after loading /chunk neither /chunk or /meta are loading for me anymore. I just want the entire graph in one picture, is that too much to ask?

Adding /network to the end of a repo URL in github gets me an image something like this

[image]

You can click and drag it side to side, but for the life of me I have not been able to get more than a small segment to show at one time.

**Is the any tool to generate the entire network graph in one image file?**

I don't want a chunk of the graph, I want to view the entire graph.
I saw http://gitup.co/ mentioned in another question, but it appears to be OS X only. A linux or a microsoft solution would work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be exported to a picture, or are you just looking for a tool to see the graph?

Comment: @crea1 I really do want to be able to export a picture,  I can see the graph on the site. However any tools to see the graph would be useful and appreciated.

Comment: @crea1 the real issue is that I can't screenshot it, it won't let me stretch it to my display

Comment: @crea1 at this point a tool to see the graph would be closer to anything I have figured out so far, but I really would like to have an image file.

Comment: What's about `gitk --all` ?

Comment: @usr1234567 that is useful, but I want the diagram type pictured above.

Comment: Take a look at http://gitgraphjs.com/.

Comment: @hellyale any update for http://gitgraphjs.com ?

Comment: @Edin M it looks super promising, I haven't had time to try it yet. With finals and final projects this week it might be a day or two. You should put it as an answer though, I'll up it for sure, and once I try it if I can get the full graph it wins. I just need to find or make a template to match the github websites graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this problem (again), and finally was able to find a decent solution.

Here is the gist with the code below: https://gist.github.com/DinisCruz/6866dede5cdff60d97790a14490f7844

```js
function hide(selector) { $(selector).setAttribute('style','display:none')} 
function remove(selector) { $(selector).remove()} 
function remove_class(selector) { $(selector).setAttribute('class','')} 

function move_left(count)
{        
    var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
    eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
    eventObj.which = 37;  // left key
    for (i=0; i < count ; i++) {
        document.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
} 

function resize_canvas(width)
{
    document.getElementById("network").style="width:" + width; window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))
}


remove('.pagehead')
remove('.js-header-wrapper')
remove('.menu')
remove('.Subhead')
remove('.info')
remove('.btn-link')
remove('.footer')
remove_class('.container-lg')
// Note: they updated this class name from .p4-4 to .pb-4
remove_class('.pb-4')

resize_canvas('2150px')
move_left(14)
```

Related twitter thread (shows some examples): https://twitter.com/DinisCruz/status/1171411025570275329

Comment: Probably the closest to correct I've seen so far, right now I copy and run your script and console and it still seems to limit it to 1 screen of width. (I have multiple monitors) I've already marked as answer, but if you figure out how to drop the css limit of 1 screen let me know!

Answer (score 5):

My answer is not about creating image as output; but it may be helpful to those who want a useful network graph.

I've written a userscript for GitHub network page: https://github.com/maliayas/github-network-ninja

Basically it provides:

- Full-viewport network graph.
- Searchable commit list.

[Click on the image for full size.]
[image: github-network-search.png]

Answer (score 4):

This was bothering me, too. I want to see this on GitHub, without exporting any JSON. For instance, on any GitHub "Network" page, in JS console of Firefox <strike>or Chrome</strike>:

1. *(optional) Unzoom the view* (`cmd`/`ctrl` + `scroll`)
2. Execute in JS console (`cmd+opt+k` or `ctr+alt+k`):

```js
document.getElementById("network").style="width:20000px"; window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))
```

3. Press and hold right arrow key to sweep through the chart for actual rendering.

*Notes:*

- I haven't yet figured out the exact events that trigger a redraw. The script redraw seems to work only once.
- Size can be customised but too high values are problematic
- **Unzoom** step: if the repository has many forks, zooming out adjusts the height of the canvas as it is linked to `window.innerHeight`
- Active elements (commits) on the canvas are not interacting well.
  [image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, as I can't get it to redraw.

Comment: @amram99, you didn't mention what browser you were using.
Actually, the method as it was described _didn't work on Chrome_ (not sure how I managed that, probably removing some classes from different elements of DOM).

Comment: Can confirm, not working on chrome for me (github repo with tons of history, up to ~30 branches at a time)

Comment: This didn't work for me with Firerfox 94.0.1

Comment: Doesn't do anything special, scroll left and zoom out is already implemented in network and firefox.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture seems to do good job.

You need to download [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) and put it into `path`. You also need python to be available in `path`.

```sh
$ set PATH=%PATH%;C:\GraphViz\release\bin
$ git clone git@github.com:esc/git-big-picture.git 
$ cd git-big-picture
$ python git-big-picture -h
$ python git-big-picture -f png -o out.png -b # branches - look
```

Comment: Hey, I keep getting 
`fatal: 'dot' not found! Please install the Graphviz utility.` when I get to the last command. 

I've set the path manually and through cmd. 
I also changed the path to match the directory and added dot.exe to the end. Nothing seems to be working...

Comment: Can you run ```dot``` or ```dijkstra``` (another GraphViz tool) from command line, if not, then work with setting environment path until you can.

Comment: had to Ctrl;+ C `dot`

Comment: `dijkstra` ran, presented me with 

`dijkstra.exe: no node specified
Usage: dijkstra [-ap?] <node> [<file> <node> <file>]
  -a - for nodes in a different component, set dist very large
  -d - use forward directed edges
  -p - attach shortest path info
  -? - print usage
If no files are specified, stdin is used`

Gonna need coffee first =)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only visualizes what's within a single git repository - without checking github for anything, in particular other repositores of the same  name for other users. -1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using GitHub for network insight there are other tools available.

Solution 1: git log --graph --all

Solution 2: git kraken

Solution 3: git gui

To make all solutions work it is necessary to add each fork as a remote:

```
git remote add fork1 url
git remote add fork2 url
```

...and so forth. A tool which automates the process of adding all forks/repos like this would be useful.

Then perform:

```
git fetch fork1
git fetch fork2
git fetch fork3
etc...
```

A tool that can generate a batch file like this would be handy though I believe git kraken may fetch all remotes automatically.

Once all remotes/forks are added all 3 solutions will render a graph of all added forks, be it horizontally though.

By far the GitHub solution that works best is this one:

https://github.com/maliayas/github-network-ninja

no zoom yet ? but it does make the box fullscreen !